# One Screen Multiple Monitors in XUbuntu on Single NVIDIA Card

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I'd like to set up my xubuntu computer to use two or more monitors such that the monitors form a single screen. The computer in question has one NVIDIA graphics card.

This would not be an extension, simply a series of monitors which combine together to form a single display.

For example, if an application entered fullscreen it would span all the monitors.

So, instead of two screens on two monitors, like this:

```
 _______________________ _______________________
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|           1           |           2           |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|                       |                       |
|_______________________|_______________________|
          |   |                   |   |
          |   |                   |   |
         /_____\                 /_____\
```

I want one screen across two monitors, like this:

```
 _______________________ _______________________
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                       1                       |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|_______________________ _______________________|
          |   |                   |   |
          |   |                   |   |
         /_____\                 /_____\
```

Any suggestions as to how to accomplish this? It is my understanding that on nvidia cards this was once possible using TwinView, which has since been deprecated.